# random no generation in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i want to show random no but that no should be below the last sl. no of mysql id.

I can do this with php rand function

```
   $noum=rand(1,100000);
```

but in this case i am predicting that no will be below 100000 but if it goes beyond 100000 i will miss those nos and rand will generate always between 1 and 100000

is there any method which will not increase the load of mysql and do exactly what i want.

in my case i can generate some small seperate php file which will store data of last id in seperate table and i can get the highest no but it is not good as i have to make two mysql request which i dont want. any other idea will be good. so that i can show random post including latest.

i dont want to use order by id as it will show lo

Comment: Use a select query to make a count of the id's. Then, use that count as a $var and then use it in the $noum like $noum=rand(1,$countid)

Comment: what are 'no', 'sl', 'lo' ?

Comment: @ChrisG again this will have two query, that solution i already have

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sorry for that it is simply mysql id autoicrement

Answer (score 1):

Select all columns from post_table where ID starts from random but never go beyond max ID with limit of 5 results.
If you want more random within this result just shuffle it with PHP.

```
SELECT * FROM  post_table WHERE id >=
FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) * ( SELECT MAX( id ) FROM post_table ) ) LIMIT 5
```

Comment: it will create heavy load on Mysql and inturn WHM?